# Identifying Unknown/Private/Restricted calls in my Android app

Tags: android, phone-call

I use a simple projection in my contentObserver to detect missed calls.

```
String[] projection = new String[] {Calls.NUMBER, Calls.DATE};
```

and later ...

```
String number = cursor.getString(0);
```

I would like to be able to identify calls with no caller ID. A quick experiment showed that the number returned was "-2" for a "Restricted" call (from a real phone, using #31#). On the emulator using "#" as phone number, shows up as a call from "-1", reported as "Unknown".

I cannot find any documentation to confirm this. Is simply looking for a negative number or a "-" prefix a reliable way of identifying such calls?

Answer (score 2):

You can use another colum: `Calls.NUMBER_PRESENTATION` that have the following possible values:

- `PRESENTATION_ALLOWED`

  - Number is allowed to display for caller id. Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)
- `PRESENTATION_RESTRICTED`

  - Number is blocked by user. Constant Value: 2 (0x00000002)
- `PRESENTATION_UNKNOWN`

  - Number is not specified or unknown by network. Constant Value: 3 (0x00000003)
- `PRESENTATION_PAYPHONE`

  - Number is a pay phone. Constant Value: 4 (0x00000004)

A call from a restricted ou unknown number the field value will be 2 or 3. So you can do something like that:

```
String[] projection = new String[] {
    Calls.NUMBER, 
    Calls.DATE, 
    Calls.NUMBER_PRESENTATION
};
```

and later ...

```
String number = cursor.getString(0);
String type = cursor.getString(2);
if(type == "2" || type == "3") { 
   number = "RESTICTED OR UNKNOWN";
}
```